# Rails 6: AJAX data not reaching controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to make a pretty standard ajax call, this is my code:

```
// app/javascripts/packs/contacts.js
jQuery(() => {
  $(".upload-contacts-button").on("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //...

    $.ajax({
      url: "/pre-parse-contacts",
      type: "post",
      data: { my_param: random_param },
      success() {},
    });
  });
});
```

This is my route:

```
post 'pre-parse-contacts', to: 'contacts#pre_parse_contacts', as: 'pre_parse_contacts'
```

For some reason the data I send in the ajax request never reaches the controller, when I try to `puts params` in the controller action I get this result:

```
------- DEBUG --------
{"controller"=>"contacts", "action"=>"pre_parse_contacts"}
```

I'm sure the ajax call is made, even the js.erb view tries to render but I get errors due to I need the data I send in the ajax call. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I found the answer to my issue, it seems I was trying to send an array of strings in the params of the ajax request, this is why it was never reaching the controller.

joining the array made the trick:

```
        $.ajax({
          url: "/pre-parse-contacts",
          type: "post",
          data: { my_param: random_param.join() },
          success() {},
        });
```